# Identify the Regex for a single line comment through file I/O

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer

```
"//"+(.*)?"\n"
```

I am using GNU's Flex and Bison. I'm trying to identify a single line comment that goes to the end of a line, this regex works when I type a comment into terminal but when I try to read from a file it breaks up the comment into:

/

/

comment

more

comment

Comment: Please show your flex source. Otherwise, it is difficult to help.

Comment: By the way, both the + and the ? operators in that regex are unnecessary. `"//".*` would work fine. (That will leave the newline to be lexed by your whitespace pattern.)

Comment: This almost works perfectly, however it gets rid of all the other tokens after the comment

Comment: What other tokens after the comment? The comment goes to the end of the line; there are no other tokens on that line. (If that is not your expectation, you need to edit your question to be a lot more clear.)

Comment: Not on that line, the tokens on the next line

Comment: If you are really using flex, then `.` will not match a newline character. If you are using "something like flex", then who knows. And please *improve your question*; don't add details in comments.

Comment: I am using the real flex, what do you mean by . will not match a newline character?

Comment: I mean that the `.` in a regex (as in `.*`) matches anything but a newline character. So it won't match the newline at the end of the line. If you want any more help, you *must* edit your question and add the relevant parts of your flex source file.